# Django Form is not displaying inside template file and not getting any error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am new in Django and creating one blog application and below to my detail post page and trying to display comment form but i am not getting form even i have used csrf also and not getting any error while running server.

However other things like buttons and comment is showing in web browser.

```
1.models.py

    ######Model related to comment
# We required to create a Model to save comments
# We required to create a model based form to submit comments
# We required to create a view function to process comments and save to the database
# We have to edit post_detail.html to display list of comments and add a form to submit
# comments
class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email=models.EmailField()
    body=models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #now order we can define.

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created',)

    #now let me take str if any person want to display comment object.
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Commented by {} on {}'.format(self.name,self.post)
    #Means if any person want to display my comment object sir simply return o/p in above form :)
#Now after creating comment model we need to run migration and migrate and need to register inside admin.py

    
from blog.forms import CommentForm
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='Published',publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    #now to implement comment we will use related name means post.comments (comment related to this post)
    comments=post.comments.filter(active=True)#i got all comment related to post.
    csubmit=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment=form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post=post
            new_comment.save()
            csubmit=True

    else:
        #if not POST then we need to display form.:)
        form=CommentForm()
            ###lets visualize above 3 lines user will submit only 3 field data (name email and body but for which post that we are associating here.)
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',{'post': post,form:'form',csubmit:'csubmit','comments':comments})


3.post detail template
```

Here i am trying to display comment form.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% extends 'blog/base.html'%}

    {%block title_block %}
    {{post.title}}
    {%endblock%}


    {%block content%}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p id='date'>Published on {{post.publish}} by {{post.author|title}}</p>
    {{post.body|linebreaks}}<br>

    <div class="container1" align="center">
        <!--####Now here below to detail post i'll enter email button href which will open post and email form.-->
        <a href="/{{post.id}}/share" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Share Post By Email</a>
        <!--Note: target_blank will open page in new tab.-->
    </div>

    <!--#######adding comment section below to post######-->
    {% with comments.count as comment_count %}
    <h2>{{comments_count}} Comment{{comments_count|pluralize}}</h2>
    {%endwith%}

    <!--#now lets display comments:)-->
    {%if comments%}
    {%for comment in comments%}
    <p id='ch'> comment {{forloop.counter}} by {{comment.name}} on {{comment.created}}</p>
    <div class="commentbody">{{comment.body|linebreaks}}</div><hr>
    {%endfor%}

    {%else%}
    <p>There is no Comment Yet!!You are the first to comment on this..</p>
    {%endif%}
    <!--###Now if comment is Submitted then we need to display form to end user.-->

    {%if csubmit%}
    <h2>Hey!,Your commented has submitted successfully. </h2>
        {%else%}
    <!--          <p id="submit1">Please submit your comment.</p>-->
                    <form method="post">
                  {{form.as_p}}
                  {%csrf_token%}
                        <input type="submit" name="" class='btn btn-lg btn-success' value="Submit Your Comment">
                    </form>
      {%endif%}

    {%endblock%}




4.forms.py

    from django import forms
class EmailSendForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
    email=forms.EmailField()
    to=forms.EmailField()
    comments=forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
    #here comment is not manadatory so we are taking required=False and comment can be of any size that is why we are taking text ared.

from blog.models import Comment
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=('name','email','body')
```

Comment: For one, the key/value in your context for `form` is the wrong way round - `form: 'form'` should be `'form': form`. Same for `csubmit`

Comment: @lain Shelvington  Thank You:)! .now It is working as expected.(Thanks)